# AOSP contribuition: CursorLoader for Sqlite DB instead of ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, loader, android-cursorloader

Why is there no SqliteCursorLoader in android platform? This would be similar to CursorLoader but for a SQLite DB instead of a Content Provider. I found some implementations around the web, and it seems to be useful.

Comment: @CommonsWare, One of the implementations I found was yours. Something to add? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there no SqliteCursorLoader in android platform?

Because it would be very difficult for one to fulfill the `Loader` contract. There are three things that a `Loader` needs to be able to do:

1. Do the work asynchronously. This could be handled by inheriting from `AsyncTaskLoader`, so there is no real problem here.
2. Retain the loaded data across a configuration change. This is provided by the framework, so there is no real problem here.
3. Automatically deliver updated content when the content changes.

Item #3 is where the problem lies. The only reason why this works with `CursorLoader` is because the `ContentProvider` system already has the notion of `ContentObserver` and already expects providers to make the appropriate notify calls to let the system know about data changes.

So, it is not merely having to implement a `SQLiteCursorLoader`, but also having to ensure that everywhere that you modify the database, you raise an event (e.g., via `LocalBroadcastManager`) that the `Loader` could listen for in order to know it needs to requery the database and deliver a fresh `Cursor`.

Now, for internal purposes on a project, you might be willing to skimp on the contract and skip item #3. That's perfectly cool. However, I would not recommend distributing such an implementation (e.g., as an open source project), due to that limitation. And this is why I discontinued my `SQLiteCursorLoader` (beyond a general belief that the `Loader` framework is a failed abstraction).